# could not find com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am trying to push notifications by firebase in my app, but I have some problems. I cannot import these:

`import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ekY.png

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add the Firebase Job Dispatcher dependency to your Gradle file.

**1.** Add this to your `build.gradle's` dependencies section:

```
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

**2.** Click Sync Project with Gradle Files to sync your project